# remote access a duel boot OS?

Tags: dual-boot, remote-access, windows-8

I've had problems with Virtual box in the past, and i feel more comfortable running a duel boot with ubuntu and windows 8, but it can be tiring having to turn off the computer when i need to skype or upload pictures onto my windows 8(main OS) account. Is there any way i can remote access my ubuntu OS from inside windows, or vise versa(which ever would be easier)? Im trying to find an efficient way to switch between my OS systems without the painstaking shut down and start up.

Answer (score 0):

NO you can't. Ubuntu and windows uses same hardware. So they can't be used simultaneously.

Why not create a ntfs partiton which is accessible in both  OS. And skype is available for ubuntu too.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do something like you described is by using Virtualbox or the like. Or really running the OSes on different machines.